# an idea for refreshing the Ubuntu 16.04 system

Tags: 16.04, pip, purge

I have some problems installing software and am wondering about refreshing the whole system.
Can I list my installed packages using `pip freeze` and purge them using `apt-get sudo apt-get purge package` for every single package name?
If it is not a good idea, how to fully refresh the system?

Comment: Packages don't sit on top of the OS - the entire OS is made up of thousands of deb packages. If you explain your problem, we may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: The comment below by @James, albeit not an answer *per se*, has the merit of pointing out the obvious you seemed to have missed. As above, it would be much better to describe / ask about the actual problem.

Comment: thanks, I have problems related to installation of [OpenCV](http://askubuntu.com/questions/891478/the-problem-related-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-or-debian)

Answer (score 2):

No, removing every single package is not a viable plan. An operating system is *made up* of packages as [this comment pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/q/891832/#comment1395141_891832). For example, the package manager, APT, that you would use to uninstall all packages, is itself a package. How will you reinstall packages after purging the package management system (actually there is a way, but it requires another package...)?

If you look at your system and have thoughts of purging every single package, you would be much better off creating a new bootable flash drive and doing an **Erase disk and install Ubuntu**.

Standard caveats apply, like, make sure to back up your data first.

Comment: Please don't use "answers" for comments.

Comment: it's not a comment.  it's an answer.  OP asked two questions, I answered both with a sound practice, based on first-hand experience.

Comment: It's a comment at best. Answers here should have higher standards, but so should the questions and this  is arguably *not* the case here . That said, please also read the comment I posted in the question itself mentioning the very good point you made.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I disagree. "You can't" is an answer. However, it would be nice if the answer were improved to include an explanation of why it is not possible to do this, as [user535733's comment](http://askubuntu.com/q/891832/#comment1395141_891832)  begins to offer. I am going to edit the post a little so that I can upvote it. James, please feel free to re-edit if you can explain more clearly than me.